# Have method wait until JFrame is disposed

Tags: java, swing

I have tried and tried and tried and failed at this. I've looked at all related questions on SO and nothing is working for me!

I have a method called from another class.

```
public void generateObstacles () throws IOException {

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {    
        Obstacles.NeedyDog windowPet = null;
            try
                {
                    windowPet = new NeedyDog();
                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 windowPet.setBounds(  100, 100, 1000, 400);
                 windowPet.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);  
                 windowPet.setResizable(false);
                 windowPet.setVisible( true );
                 windowPet.pack();
                 windowPet.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

          @Override
                 public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
          @Override
                  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {}
          });
                 }
          }).start();      

         System.out.println( "Don't move on until it closes" );
```

}

I need the user to work with NeedyDog's JDialog frame, and for it to dispose before the generateObstacles method moves on to the print statement, but it moves on immediately and prints it onto the console.

Here's my NeedyDog class:

```
private class NeedyDog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

public NeedyDog() throws IOException
    super((Window)null);
    setModal(true);
    // Code to setup the JDialog
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{
    final JFrame window = (JFrame)SwingUtilities.getRoot(this);

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("buyball")) {
        user.addCoins( -3 );
        dogTalk.setText(dogTalk.getText() + "\nVery nice. Now I want "
            + "yeh teh play with me!!");
        ball.removeActionListener(this);
        ball.setText("Oops. Try buying something else.");
    }

    else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("buybone")) 
    {
        user.addCoins( -5 );
        dogTalk.setText(dogTalk.getText() + "\nWow bone very wow much"
                + " thanks bye.");
        if (dogTalk.getText().contains("Very nice.")) 
            {
                window.setTitle( "Obstacle overcome!-Dog is happy with"
                    + " a ball AND bone! Closing window...");
            }
            else  
            {   
                window.setTitle( "Obstacle overcome!-Dog is happy!"
                    + " Closing window...");
            }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    //Wait 5 seconds before exiting
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    window.dispose();
                }
            }).start();       
        }
```

}

Comment: a) Which method of which class do you want to wait for what? b) Please provide a minimal compilable example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple: don't use a JFrame but rather use a **modal** JDialog as this behavior is exactly what the modal dialog has been built for.

And regarding:

> I have tried and tried and tried and failed at this. I've looked at all related questions on SO and nothing is working for me!

This question has been asked many many times, most answers with the same or similar solutions. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+wait+for+a+JFrame+close)

Also check out [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

If you need more specific code help, then please try to condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words, a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Indeed, as @MadProgrammer suggests, most all Swing code should be run on the Swing event dispatch thread or EDT.

Comment: Thanks. I got rid of the thread. I AM using dialogs instead of JFrame, but I'm not sure if it is modal or not. I'll try compile it down to a MEP.

Comment: @user1217: for a JDialog to be modal, you either need to set it so in its constructor or you need to explicitly call `setModal(...)` or `setModalityType(...)` on it. Please search through your code and let us know (or better show us) if you do this.

Comment: Yes I did exactly that and it works! Thanks so much.